# VBA: referencing an excel file when multiple excel files are open

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet running the below code, to click a button on itself to run some code every once in a while, with one excel sheet open it works flawlessly, but if you open a second, it will give "subscript out of range"
My assumption is the context of the command is failing because it isn't sure which open excel sheet to reference, but with a bunch of googling I haven't been able to find a solution that would work.  Working code would be nice but I'd like to understand why this is happening too, I figured with the entire filename being stated it would be able to find itself.

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:02:30"), ("'Filename.xlsm'!Sheet2.CommandButton1_Click")
```

Comment: What line of code causes the error?

Comment: Thats the fun part, it isn't that type of error, it just has an "OK" box

Comment: The error is likely in the `CommandButton1_Click` code - it was probably written assuming a direct click from a user, not a programmatic click like the one you're implementing here (so it may make some assumptions about what the active workbook/sheet is).  If you just get an "OK" button when it errors then maybe try setting your error handling to "break in class module"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. Never call an event handler. Instead of calling `CommandButton1_Click` you should put all the code in to a dedicated procedure which is then called by `CommandButton1_Click` and your `.OnTime`. NOTE: This code should be in a regular Module, not in the code-behind a sheet.
2. VBA is single threaded. So your `.OnTime` can't run if some other code is already running.